# How can I declare the variable from the list in ADODB query?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have a liste of choices with 100 variables: I would like to click on this list and use tis variable in my ADODB query:
I don't know how to declare the chosen variable from list (for exemple, if I choose the LFG -CORTAGE - 999) in the query.

My list:
.com/cfm5G.png

Comment: No spaces allowed in the variable names, no "-" character, too... Try using "_". `LFG_CORTAGE_999 As String` should be OK.

Comment: Thank you, but It's not what I want. )

Comment: I would like to clic on the list and use the choosen variable in my ADODB query

Comment: I have 100 variables on the list

Comment: So it's may be LFG_CORTAGE_999 or COURTAGE-13 or LPP or LKL ...

Comment: So, you looks to not describe your problem in a way to be understood... You should use there `Public Sub N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription(strQ as String)` and use `strQ` inside the `Sub` (`" where sousc.no_police = '" & strQ & `). Then pass the real value to the function. Something like this `N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription "LFG -CORTAGE - 999"`. Or extract it from the list you are speaking about...

Comment: Did you get my point? Should I post an answer in order to show you how the code to be used? Would you like the code to run when the drop-down cell will change its value?

Comment: Thank you ! I'll test this. Yes, I updated my question, it wasn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how to put the value from list to strQ ?

Comment: I would like to know the address of the cell having the drop-down list. Then, I will rapidly post an answer to automate the call...

Comment: Thank you, the columns are EF, the line is 15, I added the picture to my message.

Comment: I am afraid, I do not understand what you mean... Do you use a merged range? If yes, its address is the top left cell address. If not, please clarify what you meant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module and start changing the drop-down options. But there is a problem in your code: The the parameter 'cnn_Pegase' is not declared and defined.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
        N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Sub N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription(strQ As String)
    'Please, note that the parameter 'cnn_Pegase' is not declared and defined.
    'Properly declare it and give to it the necessary value, before running the code...
    Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
    RECSET.Open "select cond_gene.s_no_cg from db_dossier sousc, db_protocole proto, db_tiers tiers, db_cond_gene cond_gene, dr_protocole_cg protocole_cg, db_personne pers, db_contrat cont " & _
                " where sousc.no_police = '" & strQ & "' and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_dossier = cont.is_dossier and cont.is_cg = cond_gene.is_cg", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
        If Not RECSET.EOF Then
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription_C11").Value = RECSET.fields("s_no_cg").Value
        Else
            Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription_C11").Value = ""
        End If
    RECSET.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, When you tell "changing the drop-down options", do you mean the list ? The cnn is declared, I just didn't put it to my message :)

Comment: @Marie: But what you name a 'list' isn't it a drop-down obtained by a cell Data Validation? If yes, the answer is Yes. Please try changing its values and see what's happening...

Comment: Hello, sorry, last question. )) Maybe you know how to retrieve last digits frome the data : if my variable is LKM - 999 i would like to have only 999, there is some function like a SCAN (strQ,1,-1) ?

Comment: @Marie: Glad I could help! You can use `999 = split("LKM - 999", " - ")(1)`...

Comment: Can I do that like:  N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription Target.split("Value", " - ")(1)

Comment: I need only the digits in my query

Comment: @Marie: In principle, yes. Do you all the time have the same pattern? I mean "xxxxxx - yyy"... to extract the part after " - ". If  not, you can simple try `Right("your string", 3)`. And yes, but not in that way... You can try `N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)`

Comment: Thank you, I have always "-" and after the pattern like PM122 or 123 or KMMMM

Comment: I think that split(Target.Value, " - ")(1) is better

Comment: @Marie: I prefer it, too. That's why I proposed it firstly.  Did you try the code in this way? Anyhow, it will return even a different number of digits. I mean, everything after the " - " separator...

Comment: I'm trying but it seems to doesn't work but I have no error (

Comment: I do not understand where you tried putting your code... If you tried editing my code answer, this is not accepted. In such a case, please edit your question and place the code you are trying. But faster, because I must leave my office in about 30 - 35 minutes. If not, please explain what you want saying... Beside that, please put a break on the first code line (click in the code line and press F9) and then press F8 to move from line to line... In this way you can see what your code does.l

Comment: @Marie: I replied but now I observed that I did not tag you...

Comment: @Marie: What I would also like knowing is: Does your `Sub` work if you call it, supplying the appropriate string, but not called from the event? I mean, having a piece of code (in the same module) with a single code line: `N_CG_bulletin_de_souscription "Your string"`... Then, are you sure that `Events` are enabled? in order to check that, add the next line on the code event `MsgBox "It works..."`.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
     Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE").Value = Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1).Value
 
    End If
    
End Sub

Comment: I think this doesn't work, I tested with cell Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE").Value

Comment: Maybe beacause the liste is in column E and F ?

Comment: I mean, than when I do the test:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
       GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
       Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE").Value = "test"
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I don't have the value "TEST" in the cell.

Comment: What is "GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE", which you use to allocate the "test" string? Is it a named range? If yes, which is its address? If not, what is it? Don't you receive any error? If not, are you sure that you are looking for it in the right sheet?

Comment: I would like to make a test: click on the list and put the value from list to anoter cell.

Comment: Just to test this Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
       GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
    End If
End Sub

Comment: For exemple, I click on the list and I put the value "test"

Comment: Where/how do you "put the value 'test'? Do you mean in the event code? You can simple test it with a simple code line: `MsgBox Target.value`.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
       GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
       MsgBox Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Thank you! When I change the value in the list I don't have the message in the Box. (

Comment: Then, your "list" does not exist on the "E15" cell! In which cell is this "list", in your worksheet? Can you post a **real picture**? Real means to see the rows and columns labels...

Comment: I have a "fusion" of columns E and F

Comment: What this "fusion" should mean? Do you mean merge cells? If yes, are this "fusion" on the 15th row, as you said?

Comment: I put the image of list  in the and of message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227349/discussion-between-faneduru-and-marie).

Comment: Sorry, I have an error, when I go to ADODB sql , the variable strQ is not resolved (I put the image on my message). But MesagBox is correct (I have the last digits). I don't know how to declare the digits from MsgBox to my sql request. Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by "strQ not resolved"? When code stops on error, if you move the mouse cursor over the variable, **doesn't it show those three necessary last digits**? What should I see in the "put image on your message"? I can only see a code stopped on error. What is to be seen and I am missing? If the SQL string is wrongly built, I cannot help. I do not know how the data to be processed look... What kind of help do you expect?

Comment: thank you for your message. I tested: With only "Target" I don't have the error, when I put the "Split" I have the error. I put the image to my message.

Comment: the the message box also stop to work when I put the split to the programme

Comment: I would like to kow how to use Target.Value with Split in my sql query, beacause for the query I need only the last digits :) Thank you !

Comment: I clearly told you: If you have a string with the pattern "xxxxxx - qqq", `Split("xxxxxx - qqq", " - ")(1)` returns "qqq". But, if you have `Split("xxxxxx -qqq", " - ")(1)`, or `Split("xxxxxx- qqq", " - ")(1)` or `Split("xxxxxx - aaa - qqq", " - ")(1)` it will not return what you need. I do  not know what strings are in your so named "list"! If all have the correct pattern try using `CLng(Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1))` in order to force it to be consider as string. If it does not work, please comment all event code lines and keep only the `MsgBox` and play with the list elements and see...

Comment: In fact, should the last three digits be a `String`, like I assumed or a number? In such a case, the processing will be exactly vice versa. But **you** must know that...

Comment: thank you. I have the other error (I'm tasting the value target without Split). The sql query doesn't work: the error is 3709, the connexion is not valide, but I put the right code, when press F8 I see that the call Connexion is run

Comment: Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
   Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
        MsgBox Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
    
GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Target.Value

    End If
End Sub

Comment: but this code doesn't work : 
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
   Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
        MsgBox Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
    
GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)

    End If
End Sub

Comment: the last digits are like PM1222, 2345, KL256 :)

Comment: I am not sure that you know what you are doing, no offence... If `GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Target.Value` **works**, this only could mean that **you do not need only the three last digits, you need the whole string**... The split is able to extract all the digits after " - " separator, no matter of the digits number or whatever...

Comment: Duru GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Target.Value doesn't work, the message Box works, when I put GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1) the message Box doesn't work

Comment: You said "I mean that this code works :"... Please, try calling the Sub from another sub, near it. Call it as `GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE 999`, or put anything else (which should work) instead of 999. **Does it work**?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "E15" Then
MsgBox Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE "A17327"
End If
End Sub

Comment: I have a question: do I put the connexion in right place in my programme ?

Comment: I posted the image to my message

Comment: The code of main programme is in the chat. Could you confirm me please that connexion is in right places ? Thank you

Comment: I put Public Sub GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE(ByRef strQ As String)

Comment: With ByRef it works, have splited variable in my sql

Comment: BUT :( I still have the error of connexion, I think that I put the connexion in a wrong place

Comment: The default is `ByRef`. It maybe considers that taking the range from a cell you need to process it and returned back its value, but it is a wrong assumption. Anyhow, if it requires it, put it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset?view=sql-server-ver15) the topic of `Recordset.Open`...

Comment: I changed the code like that : 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
        Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
    End If

    Dim TabRes() As String
    If Target.Value = [E15].Value Then
        ReDim TabRes(0 To UBound(Split([Target], ",")))
        For i = LBound(TabRes) To UBound(TabRes)
            TabRes(i) = Split(Split([Target], ",")(i), "-")(1)
        Next i
    End If
    MsgBox TabRes(0)
    GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE TabRes(0)
End Sub

Comment: I cannot understand too much from the code written in a comment, presented in this way and not explaining the context? How should I have an opinion if I do not know anything about your comma delimited string which apparently you try passing... I am busy now and some time I cannot even check the message.

Comment: the problem is in joining the tables, I tested the programme with some simple tables, there is no error. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227484/discussion-between-marie-and-faneduru).